# Splitting a trigonometric equation into cases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am not understanding this step in a solution I found. We are solving

$$y=\frac{-2y}{1-y^2}$$ where $y=tan(x)$.

The solution says that we can now split this into two cases, case 1 where $y=0$ and case 2 where $y\neq0$, **I do not understand how we know that we can split up into two cases at this point, please advise**. What's the motivation?

(As a side note, the cases are

case 1, y=0 $$x=k\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$$
case 2, $y\neq0$ $$1-y^2 = -2 \iff y^2 = 3$$ then $$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$$).

Comment: $y=\frac{-2y}{1-y^2} \implies  y^3=3y \implies y^2=3$ or $y=0$ so in a sense $y=0$ might be seen as a separate case

Comment: You can always split into two cases, you either have $y=0$ or you don't have $y=0$ so $y\neq 0$. As for why you would split it into two cases, so you can safely divide both sides by $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would be tempted to cancel out the term $y$ from the numerators on both sides. i.e. write it as $$1-y^2 = \frac{-2y}{y} = -2$$. That would be valid only when $y\ne0$, since you would be dividing $0$ by $0$ when $y=0$. Hence the motivation to treat $y=0$ as a special case.